# Want to know about entries in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types

In WordPress, a `wp_postmeta` table contains values like:
`gallery_images` contains serialized structure array and another row `_gallery_images` contains a value like "field_591c2fe9a6662" how do I create this value outside of WordPress.

I am using core PHP for this and database which I am using is of WordPress.

If anyone can help me.[image]

Comment: What do you mean by ` outside of WordPress`? Like a third API? Or you actually mean change from a plugin?

Comment: This particular structure is part of the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. So you're better off asking [there](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com). But I'm pretty sure that `gallery_images` is the raw data stored by the field, and the underscore version tells ACF which custom field created it, so that field settings can be taken into account when using ACF template tags.

Comment: By saying outside of WordPress I mean to say that, I am trying to do this by core PHP.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this outside WordPress?

Comment: If you don‘t want to use WordPress for that, then this is not a WordPress question but a simple PHP/MySQL question.

Answer (score 2):

You just don't do it. Manipulating directly the DB is dangerous, error prone and might fail when wordpress or plugins are upgraded or their configuration is changed.

Just create a "one time" plugin that will properly use the relevant APIs to make whatever changes you need.

Alternatively, if you need to do this from the command line, make a plugin which extends the wp-cli so you will be able to use it to trigger the changes.